# Bulk delete WordPress Post and all metadata, etc using SQL query

Tags: sql

Is it still possible to bulk delete WordPress post and it's meta data, etc using an SQL query, I tried using some queries from years ago but didn't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: you can do this with wp-cli

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to delete posts from a certain user with this method?

Comment: wp post delete $(wp post list --author=your_author_ID --format=ids)